# Положение хуже губернаторского

Tags: фразеология

Слышала такую поговорку "положение хуже губернаторского" - в смысле, хуже не придумаешь. И озадачилась: а чем плохо быть губернатором? По-моему, они очень даже неплохо живут, особенно сейчас. Так что, по-моему, для сравнения не очень удачный пример.
Или у этой поговорки какие-то другие корни и "губернатор" тут в каком-то переносном значении?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне  кажется,  что  широкую  известность  этому  выражению  должно  было  бы  обеспечить  нечто  более  доступное,  чем  коневодческое  арго  или  возмущение  губернаторов  указом  Павла Первого.  Этот  всему  свету  известный  губернатор  должен  быть  персонажем  популярного  литературного  или  фольклорного  произведения,  например  -  анекдота.  И  такой  анекдот  есть.  В  нём  рассказывается,  как  случилось  одному  губернатору  заночевать  в  гостях.  Положили  его  там  в  одной  комнате  с  маленьким  мальчиком.  И  вот  захотелось  ночью  губернатору  по  малой  нужде.  Однако,  где  нужник  он  не  знал.  Но  первый  человек  губернии  оказался  находчивым.  Встал  он  со  своей  кровати,  переложил  на  неё  спящего  мальчика  с  соседней,  и  сделал  в  детскую  койку  всё,  что  хотел.  Пусть,  дескать,  утром  на  ребёнка  подумают.  Взял  он  ребёнка,  чтобы  назад  переложить.  Но,  о  ужас !  Младенец  успел  в  губернаторскую  постель  справить  как  малую,  так  и  большую  нужду.  Поэтому  об  очень  неудобной  ситуации  и  говорят: "положение  хуже  губернаторского".       Анекдот  старый,  явно  детский.  Гимназисты  младших  классов  наверно  сильно  смеялись.  И  наверно  во  всех  гимназиях  и  других  учебных  заведениях.  И  в  молодых  советских  школах  тоже.  Так  мне  разъяснила   это  выражения  моя  мама,  школьница  начала  двадцатых.  От  своих  сверстников  я  такого  анекдота  уже не  слыхал.

Comment: А кстати, говоря о конезаводческом арго, интересно, почему вообще такого жеребца называют "губернатором"?)))

Comment: Весьма разумное предположение.

Answer (score 1):

"Губернатор" здесь - конь, роль которого в разведении лошадей состоит в дистанционном доведении лошади до "готовности" к тому, чего от неё добиваются коннозаводчики. Приблизиться к кобыле ему не дают, поэтому так метафорически ссылаются на его незавидное положение.

Comment: Очень  специфический  источник  -  сленг  коннозаводчиков.  А  как  в  широкую  публику  эта  идиома  попала?  Через  литературу?  Интересно  кто  это  сделал?

Answer (score 1):

ИСТОРИЯ СЛОВ
В. В. ВИНОГРАДОВ

Назад   Содержание  Вперед
Положение хуже губернаторского. Примером каламбурного переосмысления по омонимическому сходству может служить современное понимание иронического выражения: положение хуже губернаторского. Как известно, это выражение пошло из коннозаводческого арго. Губернатором там назывался самец-пробник, которого припускали к кобыле для ее раздражения перед случкой с породистым производителем. В литературном языке XIX в., особенно в его публицистических стилях это выражение осмыслялось применительно к положению и должности губернатора. Например, у Р.  И.  Сементковского в очерках «Силуэты администраторов» (Историч. Вест. 1892, № 2): «Поистине теперь можно говорить о ”положении хуже губернаторского“. Еще раньше у Марковича в романе «Бездна» (3, 14): «”Недаром говорят: положение хуже губернаторского“. — Он усмехнулся остроумию этой ходячей поговорки». Ср. у Чехова в «Дуэли»: «В последнее время мое здоровье сильно пошатнулось. Прибавьте к этому скуку, постоянное безденежье... отсутствие людей и общих интересов... Положение хуже губернаторского. — Да, ваше положение безвыходно, сказал фон Корен».

(Об основных типах фразеологических единиц в русском языке // Виноградов. Избр. тр.: Лексикология и лексикография, с. 154).

Answer (score 0):

Есть версия, что этому предшествовал царский указ о мат. ответственности губернаторов, если на подведомственной территории произойдёт ограбление почты (после реального случая). "Сочувствие" обеспокоенным губернаторам выразилось в иронической форме из-за понятного многим каламбура (пошли байки и т.д.)